# Broken HTML Emails in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, phpmailer

I'm using Woocommerce since today and have started the setup of our shop. Everything is working except for the emails. As you can see below they are fairly botched. The issue appears in Thunderbird and in the Yahoo webclient but not on some other weblclients (posteo for example).

[image: Screenshot of Email]

I have tried it with the default emails (result in blank emails) and with the
Kadence WooCommerce Email Designer which at least shows something (see above). I had a look at the souce code of the email and it is shown as:

```
Message-ID: <39321b957d30d5e35cbf37b35fe0679c@www.blumenwandl.at>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.27 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html>=0A<html lang=3D"de-DE" style=3D"height: 100%; position: rel=

ative;">=0A<head>=0A<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html;=

 charset=3DUTF-8">=0A<title>Blumen Wandl</title>=0A</head>=0A<body leftmarg=

in=3D"0" marginwidth=3D"0" topmargin=3D"0" marginheight=3D"0" offset=3D"0" =

class=3D"kt-woo-wrap order-items-normal k-responsive-fluid title-style-none=

 email-id-customer_completed_order" style=3D"height: 100%; position: relati=

ve; background-color: #e2e8f0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">=0A=09=09<div id=3D"=

wrapper" dir=3D"ltr" style=3D"background-color: #e2e8f0; padding: 70px 0 70=

px 0; width: 100%; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 30px; -webkit-text-siz=

e-adjust: none; margin: 0 auto;">=0A=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" cellpaddin=

g=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" height=3D"100%" width=3D"100%"><tr>=0A<td align=

=3D"center" valign=3D"top">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table=

 id=3D"template_header_image_container" style=3D"width: 100%; background-co=

lor: #e2e8f0;"><tr id=3D"template_header_image" style=3D"width: 100%; min-w=

idth: 320px;">=0A<td align=3D"center" valign=3D"middle">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" widt=

h=3D"100%" id=3D"template_header_image_table"><tr>=0A<td align=3D"center" v=

align=3D"middle" style=3D"text-align: center; padding-top: 10px; padding-bo=

ttom: 10px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<p style=3D"margin-b=

ottom: 0; margin-top: 0;"><img src=3D"http://themes.kadencethemes.com/ascen=

d-premium-3/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/example_email_logo_acme.png" alt=3D"=

Blumen Wandl" width=3D"200" style=3D"border: none; display: inline; font-we=

ight: bold; height: auto; outline: none; text-decoration: none; text-transf=

orm: capitalize; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; width: 100%; max-width=

: 200px;"></p>=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></ta=

ble>=0A<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"670=

" id=3D"template_container" style=3D"background-color: #ffffff; overflow: h=

idden; border-style: solid; max-width: 670px; border-top-width: 5px; border=

-color: #4299e1; border-radius: 0px; border-right: 0px solid #e2e8f0; borde=

r-bottom: 0px solid #e2e8f0; border-left: 0px solid #e2e8f0; box-shadow: 0 =

1px 4px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1); width: 100%; min-width: 320px;">=0A<tr>=0A<td =

align=3D"center" valign=3D"top">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09<!-- Header -->=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=

=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"670" id=3D"template_hea=

der" style=3D'border-bottom: 0; font-weight: bold; line-height: 100%; verti=

cal-align: middle; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial,=

 sans-serif; background-color: #ffffff; color: #4a5568; max-width: 630px; w=

idth: 100%; min-width: 320px;'><tr>=0A<td id=3D"header_wrapper" style=3D"pa=

dding: 36px 48px; display: block; text-align: left; padding-top: 40px; padd=

ing-bottom: 40px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<div class=

=3D"subtitle" style=3D'font-size: 18px; line-height: 24px; font-family: "He=

lvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; fo=

nt-weight: 500; color: #a0aec0;'>THANKS FOR YOUR ORDER</div>=0A=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<h1 style=3D'ma=

rgin: 0; text-align: left; font-size: 30px; line-height: 40px; font-family:=

 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal=

; font-weight: 600; color: #4a5568;'>ORDER COMPLETE</h1>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A<!-- End Header -->=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09</tr>=0A<tr>=0A<td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top">=0A=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09<!-- Body -->=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=

=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"670" id=3D"template_bod=

y" style=3D"max-width: 630px; width: 100%; min-width: 320px;"><tr>=0A<td va=

lign=3D"top" id=3D"body_content" style=3D"background-color: #ffffff; paddin=

g-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<=

!-- Content -->=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" c=

ellpadding=3D"20" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"100%"><tr>=0A<td valign=3D"top=

" style=3D"padding: 0px 48px 0; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px;">=

=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<div id=3D"body_content_inn=

er" style=3D'color: #575f6d; text-align: left; font-size: 14px; line-height=

: 24px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif=

; font-weight: 400;'>=0A<p style=3D"margin: 0 0 16px;">Hi there. Your recen=

t order on Blumen Wandl has been completed. Your order details are shown be=

low for your reference:</p>=0A=09<div style=3D"clear: both; height: 1px;"><=

/div>=0A=09=09=09<h2 style=3D'display: block; margin: 0 0 18px; font-size: =

20px; line-height: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-to=

p: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Robo=

to, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal; font-weight: 600; text-transform=

: uppercase; color: #4a5568; text-align: left;'>=0A=09=09=09Bestellnummer 8=

8 (16. M=C3=A4rz 2020)=09=09</h2>=0A=09=0A=09=09=09<div class=3D"email-spac=

ing-wrap" style=3D"margin-bottom: 40px;">=0A=09=09=09<table class=3D"td" ce=

llspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"6" border=3D"1" style=3D'color: #575f6d; bor=

der: 1px solid #e5e5e5; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, A=

rial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; background-color: #f7fafc; border-=

width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 100%;'>=0A<thead><tr style=3D"backg=

round-color: #edf2f7;">=0A<th class=3D"td" scope=3D"col" style=3D'color: #5=

75f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Ne=

ue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; border-wi=

dth: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; pad=

ding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: left;'>Produkt</th>=0A=09=

=09=09=09=09=09<th class=3D"td" scope=3D"col" style=3D'color: #575f6d; bord=

er: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvet=

ica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; border-width: 0px; b=

order-style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: =

20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: left;'>Preis</th>=0A=09=09=09=09=09<=

/tr></thead>=0A<tbody>=0A<tr class=3D"order_item">=0A<td class=3D"td" style=

=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px; font-family: =

"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2=

f7; min-width: 60px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top: 1=

4px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-al=

ign: left; vertical-align: middle; word-wrap: break-word;'>=0A=09=09=09<p s=

tyle=3D"margin: 0 0 16px; margin-bottom: 0;"><strong>Oregano</strong></p>=

=0A<p class=3D"inside-quantity" style=3D"margin: 0 0 16px; margin-bottom: 0=

;">Quantity: 1</p>=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09<td class=3D"td" style=3D'color=

: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetic=

a Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; min-w=

idth: 60px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padd=

ing-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: left=

; vertical-align: middle;'>=0A=09=09=09=09<span class=3D"woocommerce-Price-=

amount amount">5,00=C2=A0<span class=3D"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">=

=E2=82=AC</span></span>=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09</tr>=0A<tr style=3D"backgrou=

nd-color: #edf2f7;">=0A<th class=3D"td tlabel-zwischensumme" scope=3D"row" =

colspan=3D"1" style=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: =

12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; =

border-color: #edf2f7; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top:=

 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-=

align: left;'>Zwischensumme:</th>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td class=3D"td=

 tvalue-zwischensumme" style=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; =

padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, san=

s-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; min-width: 60px; border-width: 0px; border-=

style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; =

padding-right: 20px; text-align: left;'><span class=3D"woocommerce-Price-am=

ount amount">5,00=C2=A0<span class=3D"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">=

=E2=82=AC</span></span></td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr>=0A<tr>=0A<th clas=

s=3D"td tlabel-lieferung" scope=3D"row" colspan=3D"1" style=3D'color: #575f=

6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue"=

, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; border-width=

: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; paddin=

g-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: left;'>Lieferung:</th>=0A=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td class=3D"td tvalue-lieferung" style=3D'color: #575=

f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue=

", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; min-width: =

60px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padding-bo=

ttom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-align: left;'>Abh=

olung vor Ort</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr>=0A<tr style=3D"background-c=

olor: #edf2f7;">=0A<th class=3D"td tlabel-zahlungsmethode" scope=3D"row" co=

lspan=3D"1" style=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12=

px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; bo=

rder-color: #edf2f7; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-top: 1=

4px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; text-al=

ign: left;'>Zahlungsmethode:</th>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td class=3D"td=

 tvalue-zahlungsmethode" style=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5=

; padding: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, s=

ans-serif; border-color: #edf2f7; min-width: 60px; border-width: 0px; borde=

r-style: solid; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px=

; padding-right: 20px; text-align: left;'>Credit Card (Stripe)</td>=0A=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr>=0A<tr>=0A<th class=3D"td tlabel-gesamt" scope=3D"ro=

w" colspan=3D"1" style=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; paddin=

g: 12px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-seri=

f; border-color: #edf2f7; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; padding-t=

op: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; te=

xt-align: left;'>Gesamt:</th>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td class=3D"td tva=

lue-gesamt" style=3D'color: #575f6d; border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; padding: 12=

px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; bo=

rder-color: #edf2f7; min-width: 60px; border-width: 0px; border-style: soli=

d; padding-top: 14px; padding-bottom: 14px; padding-left: 20px; padding-rig=

ht: 20px; text-align: left;'><span class=3D"woocommerce-Price-amount amount=

">5,00=C2=A0<span class=3D"woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">=E2=82=AC</spa=

n></span></td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr>=0A</tbody>=0A</table>=0A</div>=

=0A=09=09=09<div style=3D"display: none; font-size: 0; max-height: 0; line-=

height: 0; padding: 0; mso-hide: all;"><script type=3D"application/ld+json"=

>{"@context":"https:\/\/schema.org\/","@type":"Order","url":"https:\/\/www.=

blumenwandl.at\/?page_id=3D79&amp;view-order=3D88","orderStatus":"https:\/\=

/schema.org\/OrderDelivered","orderNumber":"88","orderDate":"2020-03-16T15:=

36:13+01:00","acceptedOffer":[{"@type":"Offer","price":5,"priceCurrency":"E=

UR","priceSpecification":{"price":5,"priceCurrency":"EUR","eligibleQuantity=

":{"@type":"QuantitativeValue","value":1}},"itemOffered":{"@type":"Product"=

,"name":"Oregano","sku":"","image":"https:\/\/www.blumenwandl.at\/wp-conten=

t\/uploads\/2020\/03\/oregano-150x150.jpg","url":"https:\/\/www.blumenwandl=

.at\/?product=3Doregano"},"seller":{"@type":"Organization","name":"Blumen W=

andl","url":"https:\/\/www.blumenwandl.at"}}],"discount":0,"discountCurrenc=

y":"EUR","price":"5.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","priceSpecification":{"price"=

:"5.00","priceCurrency":"EUR","valueAddedTaxIncluded":"true"},"billingAddre=

ss":{"@type":"PostalAddress","name":"Arno M","streetAddress":"Street=

123","postalCode":"4040","addressLocality":"Linz","addressRegion":"","a=

ddressCountry":"AT","email":"my@mail.com","telephone":"12345"},=

"customer":{"@type":"Person","name":"Arno M"},"merchant":{"@type":"Organiza=

tion","name":"Blumen Wandl","url":"https:\/\/www.blumenwandl.at"},"potentia=

lAction":{"@type":"ViewAction","name":"View Order","url":"https:\/\/www.blu=

menwandl.at\/?page_id=3D79&amp;view-order=3D88","target":"https:\/\/www.blu=

menwandl.at\/?page_id=3D79&amp;view-order=3D88"}}</script></div>=09<table i=

d=3D"addresses" cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0" style=3D"b=

order-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: =

40px; padding: 0;"><tr>=0A<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"padding: 12px; min-wi=

dth: 60px; text-align: left; border: 0;">=0A=09=09=09=09<h2 style=3D'displa=

y: block; margin: 0 0 18px; font-size: 20px; line-height: 30px; padding-top=

: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; font-fa=

mily: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: n=

ormal; font-weight: 600; text-transform: uppercase; color: #4a5568; text-al=

ign: left;'>Rechnungsadresse</h2>=0A=0A=09=09=09=09<address class=3D"addres=

s">=0A=09=09=09=09=09<table cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0=

" style=3D"width: 100%; padding: 0;"><tr>=0A<td class=3D"address-td" valign=

=3D"top" style=3D"border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; background-color: #f7fafc; pad=

ding: 20px; border-width: 0px; border-color: #f7fafc; border-style: solid; =

color: #2d3748; text-align: left; min-width: 60px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09Herr Arno M<br>Street 123<br>4040 Linz=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<br>12345=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<p style=3D"margin=

: 0;">my@mail.com</p>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</address>=0A=09=09=09</td>=

=0A=09=09</tr></table>=0A<p style=3D"margin: 0 0 16px;">Danke f=C3=BCr dein=

en Einkauf.</p>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</div>=0A=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A<!-- End Content -->=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A<!-- End Body -->=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09</tr>=0A<tr>=0A<td align=3D"center" valign=3D"top">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" w=

idth=3D"100%" id=3D"template_footer_container" style=3D"background-color: #=

ffffff;"><tr>=0A<td valign=3D"top" align=3D"center">=0A=09=09=09=09=09<tabl=

e border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"10" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"670" id=3D"tem=

plate_footer" style=3D"max-width: 630px; width: 100%; min-width: 320px;"><t=

r>=0A<td valign=3D"top" id=3D"template_footer_inside" style=3D"padding: 0; =

padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 30px; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: =

20px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"10" ce=

llspacing=3D"0" width=3D"100%">=0A<tr>=0A<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"paddin=

g: 0;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table id=3D"footersocial" bo=

rder=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"10" cellspacing=3D"0" width=3D"100%" style=3D"bor=

der-bottom-width: 3px; border-bottom-color: #f7fafc; border-bottom-style: s=

olid;"><tr>=0A<td valign=3D"middle" style=3D"padding: 0; padding-top: 15px;=

 padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: center; width: 33.33%;">=0A=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<a href=3D"https://www.google.com" class=

=3D"ft-social-link" style=3D'font-weight: normal; color: #718096; font-fami=

ly: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; display: block;=

 text-decoration: none;'>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<span class=3D"ft-social-title=

" style=3D"line-height: 24px; padding-left: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-weig=

ht: 600;">CONTACT</span>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</a=

>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td=

 valign=3D"middle" style=3D"padding: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: =

20px; text-align: center; width: 33.33%;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09<a href=3D"https://www.google.com" class=3D"ft-social-link" =

style=3D'font-weight: normal; color: #718096; font-family: "Helvetica Neue"=

, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; display: block; text-decoration: no=

ne;'>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<span class=3D"ft-social-title" style=3D"line-heigh=

t: 24px; padding-left: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600;">ABOUT</span=

>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</a>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td valign=3D"middle" st=

yle=3D"padding: 0; padding-top: 15px; padding-bottom: 20px; text-align: cen=

ter; width: 33.33%;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<a hre=

f=3D"https://www.google.com" class=3D"ft-social-link" style=3D'font-weight:=

 normal; color: #718096; font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, =

Arial, sans-serif; display: block; text-decoration: none;'>=0A=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09<span class=3D"ft-social-title" style=3D"line-height: 24px; padding-left=

: 5px; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 600;">BLOG</span>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</a>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09</tr>=0A<tr>=0A<td valign=3D"top" style=3D"padding: 0;">=0A=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"10" cellspacing=3D"=

0" width=3D"100%"><tr>=0A<td colspan=3D"2" valign=3D"middle" id=3D"credit" =

style=3D'padding: 0; border: 0; line-height: 125%; padding-left: 0px; paddi=

ng-right: 0px; text-align: center; font-size: 13px; font-family: "Helvetica=

 Neue", Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: 400; color: #718=

096; padding-top: 20px; padding-bottom: 0px;'>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09<p>Blumen Wandl, 185 Berry Street, Suite 550, San Francis=

co CA 94107</p>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09</tr>=0A</table>=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</td>=0A=09=

=09=09</tr></table>=0A<table class=3D"gmail-app-fix" width=3D"100%" border=

=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" style=3D"background-color: #ffff=

ff;"><tr>=0A<td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table cellpaddin=

g=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" align=3D"center" width=3D"360"><tr>=

=0A<td cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" height=3D"1" style=

=3D"line-height: 1px; min-width: 120px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td cel=

lpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" height=3D"1" style=3D"line-he=

ight: 1px; min-width: 120px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=

=09</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<td cellpadding=3D"=

0" cellspacing=3D"0" border=3D"0" height=3D"1" style=3D"line-height: 1px; m=

in-width: 120px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</td>=0A=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=

=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr></table>=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09</tr>=

=0A</table>=0A<!-- End template container -->=0A</td>=0A=09=09=09=09</tr></=

table>=0A</div>=0A=09</body>=0A</html>=0A
```

The `Content` comment that you can see in the screenshot being in plain text happens exactly because of the following two lines in the above code:

```
g-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 20px;">=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<=

!-- Content -->=0A=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09=09<table border=3D"0" c=
```

So it is split accross two lines and for some reason not properly recombined. I tried different email layouts but none of them work as you always get an issue in some line which can either result in botched html or words with a space somewhere in the middle.

My suspicion is that this issue can be fixed by changing the content encoding. As can be seen in the long source above the Content-Transfer-Encoding is `quoted-printable`. Is it possible to switch this to base64, 7bit or some other variant that is not suceptible to this issue? And if yes, where do I need to switch this, is this a wordpress, woocommerce or a PHPMailer issue?

Thanks in advance,
Arno

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess this is a PHPMailer issue – but it's likely fixed in later versions; 5.2.27 is still shipping with Wordpress, but it's 2 years old, the 5.2 branch is no longer maintained, and there have been a bunch of fixes relating to line breaks since then in the 6.x releases. Wordpress [didn't quite manage to ship PHPMailer 6 in Wordpress 5.4](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/41750), so it will likely be in 5.5, whenever that is, so you may need to bundle your own version.

Quoted-printable encoding is generally worth avoiding, and isn't used by default, but it may be activated automatically as a workaround for very long lines.

I recommend testing with a PHPMailer 6.x version to see if that fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I could finally resolve the issue by installing the Post SMTP plugin in Wordpress which is now responsible for sending the mails.